# GMaps4Rails showing map, but no place to create location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

Im using the gmaps4Rails gem and I followed the instructions and am getting
a map but no "new location" button. 

I've watched the youtube video like 4 times and it shows on there that you don't have to create a form or anything, its all created for you.

This is my server output

```
  Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gmaps4rails-0.7.7/app/views/gmaps4rails/_gmaps4rails.html.erb (2.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (5.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.7ms)
```

I've read through all the wiki's and I found ways to customize the markers, but I don't want that. 
I just want to be able to add 1 marker to the map.
I also tried adding the .css and .js files to my app and then nothing showed up.
Does it not work on localhost ? 
Or is it because I'm trying to create the location inside the creation of another object?
 I've tried just this too:

```
      <%= f.text_field :address %>
```

But it throws a "You must provide an address" error before it creates it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the screencast, I use a scaffold generator which builds the form for me at the beginning of the video (the whole app is made from scratch)

```
rails g scaffold Character name:string address:string longitude:float latitude:float gmaps:boolean
```

You need to create your migration and controller action + views yourself if you don't use it.

I really suggest you have a look at http://railsforzombies.org to learn the basics of Rails.

Comment: Crap, I forgot scaffolds make all that for you. My problem was that the attr_accessible didn't have address in it.